# Given the phrase "Where NONE of the following are TRUE" and two statements how should a boolean logic be composed?

Tags: logic

Let's have two statements

1. **(value > 10)**
2. **(value < 25)**

And a list of items with the following values

- 10
- 20
- 30

This is what a truth table would give

```
Item  Value  (value > 10)  (value < 25)
----  -----  ------------  ------------
1     10     FALSE         TRUE
2     20     TRUE          TRUE
3     30     TRUE          FALSE
```

### Example 1

```
Where ALL of the following are TRUE
   value > 10
   value < 25
```

This one is easy and we get the following

```
Where (value > 10) AND (value < 25)
```

The result is then a single value of 20

### Example 2

```
Where NONE of the following are TRUE
   value > 10
   value < 25
```

This is where I am not sure of what to generate.

This would be "simple" as it is only a NOT of the whole expression

```
Where NOT ((value > 10) AND (value < 25))
```

However, the result is then two values (10 and 30)

From what someone would think of NONE of the two statements would be something like:

```
Where NOT ((value > 10) OR (value < 25))
```

And the result would be that no items are produced.

What is the correct meaning of NONE here?

Comment: The correct meaning is "Where (NOT (value > 10)) AND (NOT (value < 25))". Applying [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) we get: "Where NOT ( (NOT(NOT(value > 10))) OR (NOT(NOT(value < 25))) )" and the equivalent result is "Where NOT ((value > 10) OR (value < 25))" :-)

Comment: @vor, make an answer out of it..

Comment: @vor: Yepp, this **is** an answer. Please post it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct meaning is:

`"Where (NOT (value > 10)) AND (NOT (value < 25))"`.

Applying one of the [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

1) `P AND Q <=> NOT( (NOT P) OR (NOT Q) )`
2) `P OR Q <=> NOT( (NOT P) AND (NOT Q) )`

we get:

`"Where NOT ( (NOT(NOT(value > 10))) OR (NOT(NOT(value < 25))) )"`

and the equivalent final result is

`"Where NOT ((value > 10) OR (value < 25))"` :-)